# Is there a way to implement the Three.js effect composer into Aframe with VR mode disabled?

Tags: three.js, aframe

Has anyone had any luck implementing bloom effects or other post-processing effects from https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/postprocessing/EffectComposer into a scene?

I’ve come across this a few times and tried to use it but can’t seem to make it work with the latest version of Aframe https://github.com/wizgrav/aframe-effects

I know it's not possible in VR yet and depends on Three work, but is there a way to use them if I'm not intending on my scene being used in VR or AR mode?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need `VR` or `AR` mode, you can use the effect composer "directly" ([check out Don McCurdys gist](https://gist.github.com/donmccurdy/31560945d5723737e6c656a2974ab628)):

1. Create a `THREE.EffectComposer` object,
2. add passes, and
3. call the composers `render` on each renderloop .

The "hacky" part is in **3**, because you need to override `a-frame`s default behavior.

```
// assuming this is a component
init: function() {
  const renderer = this.sceneEl.renderer;
  this.composer = new THREE.EffectComposer(renderer);
  // add some passes ..
  // (...)
  // override `render`
  this.bind();
},
// we need to keep the timestamps for the composer.render() function
tick: function (t, dt) {
  this.t = t;
  this.dt = dt;
},
// Bind the EffectComposer to the A-Frame render loop.
bind: function () {
  const renderer = this.sceneEl.renderer;
  const render = renderer.render;
  const system = this;
  let isDigest = false;

  renderer.render = function () {
    if (isDigest) {
      render.apply(this, arguments);
    } else {
      isDigest = true;
      system.composer.render(system.dt);
      isDigest = false;
    }
};
```

Check it out in [this glitch](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/gftruj-aframe-composer?path=index.html%3A1%3A0);
As mentioned, all credit to Don and his gist.

---

Keep in mind - `a-frame` does not have most stuff from the [threejs examples](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/dev/examples), so you may need to include them separately (like i did with the passes and shaders in my glitch)

Comment: Any tips for when we _do_ need VR/AR mode? Found this, but looks ancient and has no instructions: https://github.com/wizgrav/aframe-effects